# Confused with Sum of squares between groups and Sum of squares between persons

Tags: anova

I am not new to Statistics. I have studied ANOVA and its terms i.e., Sum of squares between groups and Sum f squares error etc. A few days ago I have read somewhere:

> - Question 1. Define the following terms:
>
>   - a. Sum of squares between groups
>   - b. Sum of squares error
>   - c. Mean square between groups
> - Question 2. Define the following terms:
>
>   - a.    Degrees of freedom between persons
>   - b.    Sum of squares between persons
>   - c.    Mean square between persons

Now in Statistics I have read Sum of squares between groups and Error sum of squares and then we can obtain mean square between groups by dividing sum of squares between groups and error sum of squares.
But what about Question 2? Is there any difference when we say Sum of squares between groups and Sum of squares between persons? It would be really helpful if someone can help me regarding this?

Comment: Need more information. One way or two way ANOVA? What is the relation between group and person?

Comment: I have shared all the information that I had. I just read these 2 question. But either its one way or two way, its not relevant I guess, because sum of squares is a general term.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1, mean sum of squares is not $\frac{SS_{between}}{SS_{error}}$, it's $\frac{SS_{between}}{df_{between}}$. sums of squares between is also often called sums of squares (between) treatment.

For question 2, I think i agree with you that they've used bad terminology. I assume when they say sums of squares between people they actually mean sums of squares error AKA sums of squares *within* group. Their terminology *kind* of makes sense because to find SS error you take each individual and subtract the group mean. It's the variation between individuals not accounted for by the group effect. But still, it's very nontraditional terminology.

As for the rest of Question 2, the degrees of freedom are different, degrees of freedom for between is number of groups - 1,  and degrees of freedom error is number of people - number of groups. Remember, between is to do with differences between groups that's why you take the groups and subtract 1, and error (AKA within) is to do with the variance *within* groups so you take number of people and subtract number groups.

When you get MSB and MSE *then* you can divide them to get the F statistic in ANOVA.

This [link](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section4/prc433.htm) might help.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the correction, my bad. And thanks for your explanation as well. I think it makes sense.